# Export Data to Flat File using SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am trying to export a database table into delimited flat file using a SSIS package. My database table has about 31 rows and it looks like below -
[image]

When I am editing the Flat file connection manager, the preview doesn't show any rows. What is the issue? Snapshot is below -

[image]

Comment: you can only preview data in input source not in output, output will only show definition and mapings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a preview of the output file.  It will only show data if the file has been created and has data in it.